# Service to worker pattern - the best practice to transfer data from controller to view

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

So the question. We use service to worker pattern and now are looking for an appropriate pattern to transfer data from controller to view. Any help is appreciated.

**Unfortunately I couldn't attach diagram at first (it's a cool site,isn't it) as I didn't have reputation 10 and thanks to people now I can**

[image]
Comment:TemplateEngine is any alternative to jsp template engine.

So I will try explain via text.

Classes:FrontController,Controller,View,Action,Jsp files, EJB, Entity (Anemic Model). So   FrontController routes to Controller and invokes two methods of Controller by order. Controller has only two public methods processAction and processView. ProcessAction invokes Action (command pattern),so

FronController calls Controller.processAction()->Action -> EJB - >get Entity.

So here the FrontController must invoke the second method of Controller

FronController calls Controller.processView()->View -> Templating, jsp , helpers etc(at this point we need data that we have got in controller)

EDITED:
Controller.ProcessAction and Action.execute have the same signature:(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response).

What about request/response object(context object). I've read core j2ee patterns and was surprised. As I understood this object takes data from request and even makes validation. Its main goal is to give as a tool to work with data that removes the dependency of different protocols (html,xml,json). There are two reasons why I was surprised:

1. Context object was created in frontcontroller - at this step we can hardly define that context object we will use. Often there are situations what we even need another controller.
2. I think that validation must be performed in EJB. The reason is very simple if we have two kinds of clients: browser and java application than their common point is EJB. So it's in the EBJ we must make validation.

So, I am very interested in other people's opinion.

Comment: Can you show us your Service to Worker

Comment: @Siddiqui, thank you for your time - I showed it.

Comment: What's the method signature of processAction?  Probably you need a context object of some sort?  Take a look at other command pattern implementations for hints.

Comment: If you want a true service tier, you may want to decouple it from http request and response.  Interacting with those is typically more the responsibility of the web tier.

Comment: @Taylor I totally agree with you. EJB must know about http nothing. That's why we call EJB from action.execute without any response and request. But it's already in action.execute not in front controller.

Comment: Now you should have 10+ :)

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/images/mvc.png on how spring solves this problem. It basically says the dispatcher gets the correct controller which return a model. The dispatcher then pushes the model into the view. In your current case the controller has too much responsibilities.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for your points (:)) and time. I attached the diagram. Why do you think that controller has too much responsibility? It only controls the flow.

Comment: @Bart I have looked at that picture - isn't it the same I have. The question is about the best way to pass model.

Comment: Because the controller processes the view which should not be one of it's responsibilities. The *manageView()* part should be the task of an object with the sole purpose of managing views. It's a better strategy to decouple view and controller.

Comment: @Bart To tell the truth I din't think about object with sole purpose. Can you give example? I choose between two objects:controller and the view. I thought that view is responsible only for creating(!) view , but not for managing view. So controller left. I added new method and now all the view management logic is centralized.

Comment: LOL, no chat available due to the low reputation :) To keep things short have a look at [this picture](http://cdn.dzone.com/static/images/vaannila/spring/spring-mvc-pic-9.gif) and you'll see the process of a front controller that has decoupled controller from view the preferred way. In your case the view resolving part is missing or misplaced.

Comment: @Bart - :) To talk seriously all this reputation is just a foolish game. And I am sure that site this way only looses visitors. Just imagine - the site has some functionality but you can't use. What an idiot invented it? But, I looked at your picture and understood about view resolver but how model is passed to view?

Comment: @Bart I think I understood how spring works. Please correct me, if I am wrong. The center point is dispatcher. At step 1. dispatcher calls handler mapper that return a controller to dispatcher. 2. dispatcher calls controller method and gets back modelandview as one object.I suppose that model is just a hashmap. view - string,not the object 3. dispather uses one calls it and gets view object 4.passes to view model (from step2) and renders it. Righ?

Comment: Yes you got the picture. A few adjustments though... The central point is indeed the dispatcher servlet (front controller). In my experience the controller gets the model (Map) injected into the method/action as an argument and returns the name of the view as a string. That string is passed to the view resolver to resolve it to a view. Your version of using the ModelAndView is also perfectly valid though. Just use what makes the most sense to you.

Comment: @Bart Thank you. Now I got how spring works. But is it the best practice?

Comment: Yes it is. It has good separation of concerns and single responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can have GetData() in one controller, combine the GetData() in TemplateEngine layer. Or, another approach, is to add one more layer Service layer, to retrieve all the data, and controller will combine all the GetData() functions from service layer.

Thank you,